# Redirect page when form submits

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How do I redirect page after the form submit in below situation.

```html
<form action="URL" method="post" id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

So when above form submits, do below. The problem is that I can't add events on the form.

```js
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.parent.location="/thank-you/";
    },1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Normally the action URL is the intended target. Why aren't you using that?

Comment: Are yo sure this is what you want to do? After a POST, you should probably send a redirect response from the server, not the page, which might be unloaded by then.

Comment: I'm sending info to another page that opens up on another tab(with target=_blank) and process info there. I just need to redirect the form page to thank you page.

Comment: This is wrong code but this will give you idea what I want to do<script>
document.getElementById("myForm").submit(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.parent.location="/thank-you/";
    },1000);
});
</script>

Comment: Let me see if I understand: you want to display "thank you" when the user presses submit button, then redirect to the action URL, is that so?

Comment: And you are not allowed to use "onsubmit='return my_function()' "?

Comment: No, when form submits, it opens up new window send info there and process it there(This usually the thank you page for most of cases) but I want to redirect the page that has form to thank you page.

Comment: I can't fix anything on the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form onsubmit event to redirect the page but don't know why you're using javascript, I'm assuming your're using some server language like php or asp which have redirects, so after you submit to these pages I would use them to redirect to the thank you page or even better incorporate the code into the thank you page itself and just go directly there with your form submition....

Answer (score 0):

If this is really how you want to do this, you need to process your data in the form's `onsubmit` event, or the button's click event and redirect after the processing is complete...you could attach with jQuery if that's an option without modifying the form, but you didn't tag it so I don't know if you can use it.

You could get this for free using the action attribute, you know.

Comment: How do I get the <form onsubmit="function"> since I don't have access for the form. I know this is not the best way to do this but this is how the system setup already and I don't even have access to the form cause it's pulling from external site.

Comment: If you use jQuery, you can attach to the submit button's click event, or the submit event for the form without modifying the form HTML. Other Javascript frameworks probably have this capability, but I use jQuery. You could probably manually code it too if it's not an option...